# How to design like this dropDownButton with title and boxTextField?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to design like this DropDownButton with title and text field box?
[image]

Comment: Can you show us what did you try and which part of it didn't work as expected?

Comment: my dropdownbutton is normal. I dont know how to design like above dropdown